# Understanding CryptoCompare streamer data

Tags: javascript, java, websocket

I am learning to work with WebSockets (in Java-Android) and I get the following response from the CryptoCompare server:

```
5~CCCAGG~XRP~USD~4~1521460342~1000~651.6800000000001~214344993~61477290.44395565~40404715.58782694~204630354.90428987~125295222.52928983~Bitfinex~40fe8
5~CCCAGG~BTC~USD~1~8345.49~1521460342~1~8330.5~214344994~73285.13728421592~609108591.9429483~199960.38011137667~1585164124.8472543~fe9
5~CCCAGG~ETH~USD~1~537.41~355733.2471545533~190548675.34079295~1348542.794115353~679086434.3118488~f01
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/cryptoqween/cd72df49fb37ac767eb92f0a3e93f19c)'s their utility page (I only need to work with `CCC.CURRENT`). Can someone help me understand how to read this? How can I tell which field is where. Here's a link to their [Api Doc](https://www.cryptocompare.com/api#-api-web-socket-).

The utility page uses hex and fields. For example ..

```
price = 0x1
last_update = 0x8
```

Now, how do I use this info!?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is this question about [tag:javascript] and not [tag:java]? I do not see how is this question related to [tag:java]

Comment: I was trying to convert the info received from the stream (thanks to the utils provided in javaScript) in a Java application. Basically, I needed to convert the JS function unpack to a Java method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Edited since you want to do this in Java, not JS)

(Edited again since you clarified the question.)

The code that packs the data is this:

```
var mask = 0;
var packedCurrent ='';
for(var property in this.FIELDS)
{
    if(currentObject.hasOwnProperty(property)){
        packedCurrent += '~'+currentObject[property];
        mask|=this.FIELDS[property];
    }
}
//removing first character beacsue it is a ~
return packedCurrent.substr(1)+'~'+mask.toString(16);
```

So we can see that there is a [mask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)) that starts at zero, and bits are being set if the property is being sent.  You'll need to get comfortable with doing bit-masking in Java for this.

The properties are being added to the string in the order set in `CCC.CURRENT.FIELDS`.

So you can go through the mask in the order of the items in `FIELDS` (`PRICE`, then `BID`, then `OFFER`...).  Each time you find a 1, chop off the first part of the string (up to the `~`) and parse it according to the type that you've found.

Comment: That's what I thought too. How can I use that function in Java?

Comment: I have 0 experience in JavaScript

Comment: Btw. I need to use the CCC.CURRENT.UNPACK function. Not the one in trade

Comment: thank you. I'm going over it again. I'll let you know soon :)

Comment: Updated.  Hope this helps.  Please update your question to make it clear that you care about CURRENT, not TRADE.

Comment: Got it to work! Thanks for your help. Would have never known what to do if you wouldn't have told me about bit masking! Had never used it before ^^